# How to change the html meta tags with react function components

Tags: reactjs, meta

I have a simple react app and I am trying to change the meta tags of the html that is generated. I read about [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) but the examples there are for classes and not for functions. Any idea how to do that with function components?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Route path="/food/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/food/food/" component={Food} />
        <Route path="/food/new-food/" component={NewFood} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Update based on Ricin's reply:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css'
import Nav from './components/nav'
import Home from './components/home'
import Food from './components/food'
import NewFood from './components/new-food'
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Food</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Calorie Calculator" />
      </Helmet>
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Route path="/food/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/food/food/" component={Food} />
        <Route path="/food/new-food/" component={NewFood} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App
```

(Aug 27, 2019) Here is another update based on based on Ricin's reply: I added the Helmet code to the Home component instead of the App:

```
  const foods = getFoodFromDB()
  const ate = getAteFromDB()

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Food</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Calorie Calculator" />
      </Helmet>
      <Ate ate={ate} />
      <Food food={foods} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately I still see two entries in my  for the description meta tag.

Comment: `import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";` import Helmet in your functional component and then wrap your desired piece in it, nothing to do with class vs functional component

Comment: thanks! I added the Helmet tags inside the Router tags. Is that the place I should add them? I can't tell if it's working since view source show me the title I wanted but not the description (<meta name="description" content="Calorie Calculator" />>

Comment: how are you using Helmet code, can you update your question with that snippet?

Comment: I updated the body of my question

Comment: see if this works: having it outside
      <div><Helmet>
        <title>Food</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Calorie Calculator" />
      </Helmet>
<Router>...</Router>
      </div>

Comment: I tried your approach. The title changes but the meta description is still showing the default - <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app">

Comment: I noticed that the 'description' from helmet is showing at the end of the <head> but so does the default 'description'. I am not sure if that's the expected behavior. I would expect helmet to override the default one and not append it.

Comment: The default one is in your <App/> component which will always render regardless of the route thus you need to remove that and rather place Helmet inside individual component. If you dont want to do that and rather just have <Helmet/> in your APP component then you should pass in a function to your child components which handles updating value based on your child component, let me know if you want an example of that. Example updated in my answer.

Comment: I moved the Helmet code to the Home component but I still see two entries in the <head>. I added the code change at the bottom of my question.

Comment: You need to remove `<Helmet>` code from <App> component right under the `<Router>`, you dont need it there which is resulting in additional meta tag

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working example that has 2 pages and both have 2 different Helmet component meta tags which you can inspect: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-haze-2kqum

Import Helmet in your functional component and then wrap your desired piece in it, nothing to do with class vs functional component

`import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";`

I meant using inside the `Home`, `Food`, and `NewFood` component.

So your Home component would look something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

let Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet
                    title="Home"
                    meta={[
                        {property: 'og:title', content: 'Home'},
                        // Any other meta tags go here as objects or you can just add children directly inside this component.
                    ]} />
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Home;
```

Here are more examples that you can use: https://github.com/mattdennewitz/react-helmet-example